# Can Google dataflow split CSV files according to the first column?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I need to write a dataflow which consumes CSV records from a single GCS location and then writes records to several GCS locations according to the value of the first column of an CSV record.

Does Google Dataflow provide an equivalent of Hadoop's [MultipleOutFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) which gives you the ability to provide file name per record at runtime ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently possible in full generality with Dataflow.  It is on the radar, and you can track progress/contribute here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-92

If you have a small, fixed set of possible output locations, there is a workaround.  You can partition your output into separate PCollections based on the output key, then take each of those PCollections and write them out using separate TextIO.Write transforms.  To do the partitioning, you can use [Side Outputs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-outputs) or the [Partition operation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Partition).

Comment: Thank you, @danielm.  When I tried to use multiple side outputs, data from each side output goes to a separate TextIO.Write, I hit limitation on the size of JSON which defines a dataflow:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create a workflow job:The size of the serialized JSON representation of the pipeline exceeds the allowable limit.  d

Comment: Yeah, there's a hard limit on the maximum size of the job graph, so this workaround will only work for a relatively small number of distinct sinks.  How many different locations do you have?

Comment: the number of locations is relatively large in the range from 1000 to 10 000.

Comment: I have also noticed that when the number of TextIO.Write elements of the dataflow is 90, then I get "GC Overhead limit exceeded" errors. When I reduce the number of writers to 12, I don't have that error, but I get another  error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to materialize view.  Using side outputs with multiple TextIO.Write's works  for a few dozens of folders only and that doesn't meet our requirements. I think we will have to write a separate MR job to sort out records into folders.